# How to use a Array of FileWriter in android : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array

Tags: java, android, arrays, file, nullpointerexception

I have multiple files to write in and so I was trying to use a array of `FileWriter` and `PrintWriter`. I even surround the statements with try and catch but still the app crashes and give the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array

this is what I did:
In main `Activity` class I declared a array of `FileWriter`, and

```
private FileWriter outStream[];
private PrintWriter printWriter[];
```

in `onCreate` function I did this:

```
try {
           outStream[0] = new FileWriter(finalFile_Acc, true);
           printWriter[0]= new PrintWriter(outStream[0]);
     } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
try {
           outStream[1] = new FileWriter(finalFile_Gyro, true);
           printWriter[1]= new PrintWriter(outStream[1]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

PS: I can't declare and initialize the `FileWriter` and the `PrintWriter` at the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PrintWriter you should use it like this

```
    PrintWriter printWriter[];
    int numberOfPrintWriters = 10;

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    printWriter = new PrintWriter[numberOfPrintWriters];

    //using first printWriter
    PrintWriter printWriter[0] = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
     try {
        printWriter[0].write(str, 0, 26);
        //or
        printWriter[0].print("ZZZ");
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        printWriter[0].close();
    }

    //Similarly you can use other printWriters in array using their index like printWriter[i]
```

For FileWriter you can use it like this

```
  int numberOfFileWriters = 10;
  FileWriter fWriter[];
  fWriter = new FileWriter[numberOfFileWriters];
  try{
     //using first fileWriter
     fWriter[0] = new FileWriter(file, true);
     fWriter[0].write("content");
     fWriter[0].flush();

  }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{
     fWriter[0].close();
  }

  //Similarly you can use other fWriters in array using their index like fWriter[i]
```

If you want to write into a file in externalSDCard then

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + " \filename.txt");
```

Comment: It is working that way but I want to use array of FileWriter and PrintWriter.

Comment: See the modified answer that uses array of PrintWriters and FileWriters

Comment: Okay Thanks this worked. Just had to add these two lines
outStream = new FileWriter[2];
printWriter = new PrintWriter[2];